# Не могу заменить кусок кода с str_replace

Tags: php, str-replace

Хотел удалить определенный кусок кода в php-файле, решил сделать это с str_replace(). Таким образом:

```
$filename = 'check.php';
        $a = 'public function actionTitle1()
{
    $this->title = "Title 1";
    $this->meta_author = "Arandar";
    $this->meta_copyright = "Copyright © 2018 Arandar. All Rights Reserved.";

    $content = $this->view->render("title1", array(), true);

    $this->render($content);
}';
        $b = '';
        $file1 = file_get_contents($filename);
        $file1 = str_replace($a, $b, $file1);
        file_put_contents($filename, $file1);
```

Вот так выглядит файл, где нужно удалить файл с соблюдением табуляции и переносов:

```
    public function actionTitle1()
{
    $this->title = "Title 1";
    $this->meta_author = "Arandar";
    $this->meta_copyright = "Copyright © 2018 Arandar. All Rights Reserved.";

    $content = $this->view->render("title1", array(), true);

    $this->render($content);
}
```

Но увы, не работает. Файл обновляется, однако остается без изменений. Подскажите, будьте добры, в чем ошибка, ибо уже все облазил, нашел какие-то варианты на JS, однако хотелось бы на PHP.

Comment: А нет варианта замены без учета табуляции хотя бы, не говорю уже про новые строки?

Comment: С регулярными мне еще не доводилось работать..) Просто понимаете, я полностью скопировал код из основного файла в чистый, ничего не менял и там все работает, а в основном файл просто обновляется, но оно не хочет работать, как бы я ни соблюдал табуляцию, переносы строки и все остальное.. Вот что меня смущает

Comment: А какую цель вы преследуете? Зачем вам понадобилось удалять пхп код в другом пхп файле? Я предполагаю, что вашу задачу можно решить иначе, вообще без замен.

Comment: У меня есть статьи на сайте, решил сделать кнопку "удалить", чтобы все происходило автоматически, а не каждый раз переходить в файлы и чистить там все. Удаление самой статьи из папки дело нехитрое, а вот удалить код оказалось труднее. В интернете есть только информация, как удалить код с определенной строки по номеру, но я же не могу предугадать, на какой строке мне придется удалить код в следующий раз. Сейчас я пока пытаюсь заменить определенный код на пустое значение, но в дальнейшем вместо названия будут просто переменные, внутри которых будут записываться значения.

Comment: Я еще новичок, так что это единственный нормальный вариант, который пришел мне в голову. Но когда он не сработал, решил обратиться к более старшим товарищам)

Comment: Все правильно, записывается в бд, создается файл вывода этой информации и производится запись в контроллер. Вот мне как раз нужно удалить код из контроллера. Выше показано, что он содержит в себе только дополнительную информацию, а не саму статью)

Comment: Самописный. Возможно я не смог донести до вас всю суть, но это не главное. Можете подсказать другой способ удаления кода из файла?

Comment: Все работает, файл оказался багнутым, по какой-то причине не хотел изменяться. Данные скопировал в новый файл, а старый удалил, и все заработало. Спасибо, что потратили время)

Answer (score 0):

Для вашего текущего кода *(контроллер `actionTitle()`)* вполне подойдёт такой шаблон:

```
'~public function actionTitle1\(.*?\)[^{]+\{[^}]+\}~s'
```

Как видно из начала шаблона, под удаление попадает строка, начинающаяся со слов *public function actionTitle1*, и заканчивающаяся фигурной скобкой `}`. Но если в теле метода встретится ещё пара фигурных скобок, то этот вариант сработает не корректно. Именно поэтому я в комментариях говорил, что для регулярных выражений нужно учитывать все возможные варианты подстрок.

```
$str = '
    public function actionTitle1()
{
    $this->title = "Title 1";
    $this->meta_author = "Arandar";
    $this->meta_copyright = "Copyright © 2018 Arandar. All Rights Reserved.";

    $content = $this->view->render("title1", array(), true);

    $this->render($content);
}

    public function actionBody()
{
    $this->title = "Title 1";
    $this->meta_author = "Arandar";
    $this->meta_copyright = "Copyright © 2018 Arandar. All Rights Reserved.";

    $content = $this->view->render("title1", array(), true);

    $this->render($content);
}
';

echo preg_replace('~public function actionTitle1\(.*?\)[^{]+\{[^}]+\}~s', '', $str);
```

В результате вы получите строку:

```
    public function actionBody()
{
    $this->title = "Title 1";
    $this->meta_author = "Arandar";
    $this->meta_copyright = "Copyright © 2018 Arandar. All Rights Reserved.";

    $content = $this->view->render("title1", array(), true);

    $this->render($content);
}
```

Comment: Еще раз спасибо! Очень помогли)